# Why does 0x not appear when I print a memory address in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I'm trying to print a memory address in C, this is the code I'm using

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int v = 10;
    printf("Address of the v: %p\n",&v);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is supposed to start with 0x, but I don't have this thing, it shows this `0061FF14`
I am using MingW32 gcc compiler
I changed it to 64 and when I typed the code again the output is `000000A57A7FF67C`

When I use https://www.onlinegdb.com/ the output is normal with 0x

My machine is 64 bit I am using vscode editor, how do I make the address appear as normal 0x

Comment: The output of the `p` specifier is implementation defined. It's up to the implementation whether to include the `0x` or not.

Comment: *"The output is supposed to start with 0x"* Who did tell you that?

Comment: `%p` is largely intended for debugging. Addresses within a process are generally not even portable to other processes of the same system, let alone other systems, and that is why the format is left as implementation-defined rather than more fully specified by the C standard. If you want finer control over the formatting, you can convert an address to the `uintptr_t` type (defined in `<stdint.h>` and use the fuller format modifications available with the integer types, including using the `PRIxPTR` macro for the format defined in `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: If you want to control the format of printed addresses, use `#include <inttypes.h>` and `printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)pointer);`.  For myself, I prefer hex to be printed with `0xABCD0123EF456789` with the dip at the start for the `x` and the rest all full height.  If you prefer lower-case alpha characters in your hex, use `PRIxPTR` instead.  You can specify how many digits to print using, for example, `printf("0x%.12" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)pointer)`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler does standard guarantee that %p will produce the same result as printing pointer converted to integer?

Comment: @0___________ ————— No

Answer (score 2):

> Why does 0x not appear when I print a memory address in C?

Because it is not specified by the standard. The implementation can choose to print it or not.

1. Your code invokes undefined behaviour as the pointer has to have type *pointer to void (`void *`)*.
2. If you your implementation does not print `"0x"` simply add it to the format string.

```
    printf("Address of the v: 0x%p\n",(void *)&v);
```

or ***`if your implementation supports`*** it

```
    printf("Address of the v: %#p\n",(void *)&v);
```

Comment: Not the DV, I was about to comment that you never need to cast to (void*) as that is implicit, but now I found out there is one exception and that is %p in printf, well learn something new everyday.

Comment: Note that the C standard says (for the [`printf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) `#` modifier): _`#`
The result is converted to an ''alternative form''. For o conversion, …  For x (or X) conversion, … For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, … For other conversions, the behavior is undefined._. The `p` conversion specifier is one of the 'other conversions' — using `%#p` is undefined behaviour.  Obviously, a platform may define the behaviour, but you have to establish that before using it in production code.

Comment: @Fredrik, the cast is required when used in any _varargs_ function; the `printf` family is merely the most frequently encountered of these.